# Issue with printing sub-menu in ncurses with c++

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm trying to print a sub-menu associated with a main menu shown with ncurses. 
This is the way i've organized it :

1. do{} while (); loop with wgetch gets keypad input from user
2. if user presses the enter key, the subMenu entry is shown after clearing the whole screen.

Unfortunately, I can't make it past the 2nd step, the sub-menu never shows up on screen.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{ 
    std::string nameMainMenuExample = "/parent1/folder";

    std::string nameSubMenuExample = "/folder/file";

    // initialize ncurses
    WINDOW *win;
    win = initscr();
    raw();
    curs_set(0);
    cbreak();
    box(win, 0, 0); 
    refresh();
    wrefresh(win);
    keypad(win, true);
    // end initialize ncurses

    int highlight = 0;
    int choice;

    // PRESS 'a' to ESCAPE LOOP
    do {
        mvwprintw(win, 1, 1, nameMainMenuExample.c_str());
        switch (choice) {
            case KEY_UP:
                --highlight;
                if (highlight == -1) {
                    highlight = 0;
                }
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                ++highlight;
                if (highlight == 1) {
                    highlight = 0;
                }
                break;
            case KEY_ENTER:                        // Enter key pressed
                clear();
                mvwprintw(win, 1, 1, nameSubMenuExample.c_str());
                refresh();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } while ((choice = wgetch(win)) != 97); // random choice a == 97

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I just expect the sub menu to be printed on screen after ncurses clears the screen of the main menu.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to activate the submenu on the enter key, you should be checking the value `wgetch` returned against `KEY_ENTER` (which is something like 16777221 numerically), not 10.

Comment: i change it for `case KEY_ENTER:` in my code and it still doesn't work?

Comment: @ThamLeroy Time for [debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing calls to different windows (**`clear`** and **`refresh`** use **`stdscr`**) and the one your **`wgetch`** call uses is getting its own `wrefresh`.  Since the menu-window is not being refreshed, it never appears, and since **`wgetch`** does a **`wrefresh`**, **that** may additionally obscure things.

Start by making the **`wrefresh`** calls apply to the windows you want to be repainted.

Comment: I've changed and simplified my code but I have difficulties making it work? Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using `ncurses` in C++, ENTER key value is just `'\n'` 
For example:

```
case '\n':
   clear();
   mvwprintw(win, 1, 1, nameSubMenuExample.c_str());
   refresh();
   break;
```